# How can I make a textfield highlight in red only after its input is proven as incorrect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-input, background-color

I have this form (Horribly basic and messy at the moment, I know.):
[image]

This is how it looks on-load.

Here is my CSS:

```
img {
    position: fixed;
    right: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}

input:invalid {
    background-color : #ff0000;
}

input:valid {
    background-color : #99ff99;
}
```

What I want to know is how can I get the fields to be displayed as red only if and when the user is bought back to the page with incorrect inputs?

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/Daghdha/w919yb9d/) a JSFiddle with the relevant HTML, CSS, and JS.

Comment: What is your method of validation here? Can you show us a jsfiddle?

Comment: @TimMcClure I've never used jsfiddle before. Should I have my html and css in it to?

Comment: Yeah, you can put in your JS, HTML, and CSS. You can also load in external libraries and resources like jQuery if you're using anything like that. It makes it easier for us to be able to debug your issue because we get the bigger picture of what you are working with and what you are trying to accomplish. Users can also fork your jsfiddle to update and solve the issue.

Comment: @TimMcClure I can fix up the question if you'd prefer that to wading through that. I'll do it anyway before I accept an answer but I can do it before rather than after if you think it best.

Comment: yeah I would at least post your jsfiddle link in the question so others can see it easily. And FYI - your jsfiddle looks like it contains a lot of stuff that is irrelevant to your question. Try to recreate this only with relevant HTML, CSS and JS so user do not have to spend time wading through everything to figure out what is going on. For example, all of the cookie-related stuff is not necessary, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When clicking on the submit button, check the fields before you let the user continue, and if they are incorrect, `return false;` so the submit button won't refresh the page.

Then just use `yourelement.style.backgroundColor = "red";` on all the wrong elements.

Comment: If I do this, should I remove the parts of the CSS file which deal with this? Would it be alright to do this when the focus leaves a field instead of on submit?

Comment: Only the part in the CSS where you set the background of the input field to red. And of course, even better!